# Ошибка отправки формы PHP

Tags: php, html

html:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="email" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="E-Mail адресс" type="email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select class="custom-select" id="" name="typeofscam">
                                    <option value="">Вид мошенничества</option>
                                    <option value="Binary Options">Бинарные опционы</option>
                                    <option value="Cryptocurrency">Криптовалюта</option>
                                    <option value="Forex">Форекс</option>
                                    <option value="Stock trading">Биржевая торговля</option>
                                    <option value="Credit card phishing">Фишинг кредитной карты</option>
                                    <option value="Other">Другое</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select class="custom-select" style="max-width: 260px;" name="countrycode">
                                    <option value="">Код страны</option>
                                    <option data-countryCode="DZ" value="213">Algeria (+213)</option>
                                    <option data-countryCode="AD" value="376">Andorra (+376)</option>
                                    <option data-countryCode="AO" value="244">Angola (+244)</option>
                                    <option data-countryCode="AI" value="1264">Anguilla (+1264)</option>
                                    <option data-countryCode="AG" value="1268">Antigua &amp; Barbuda (+1268)</option>
                                    <option data-countryCode="AR" value="54">Argentina (+54)</option>

                                </select>
                                <input name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите номер телефона" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select class="form-control" name="invest">
                                    <option value="">Общая сумма инвестиций</option>
                                    <option value="5">Меньше чем 5K</option>
                                    <option value="10">5K - 10K</option>
                                    <option value="20">10K - 20K</option>
                                    <option value="40">21K - 40K</option>
                                    <option value="80">40K - 80K</option>
                                    <option value="100">80K - 100K</option>
                                    <option value="150">100K - 150K</option>
                                    <option value="160">150K и больше</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Отправить форму </button>
                        </form>
```

php файл

```
   <?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

try {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $code = $_POST['countrycode'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $type = $_POST['typeofscam'];
    $invest = $_POST['invest'];
    
    //Server settings                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 's31.server-panel.net';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = '_mainaccount@sh4272858.c.had.su';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '********';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('_mainaccount@sh4272858.c.had.su');
    $mail->addAddress('telesi6492@v2ssr.com');     //Add a recipient
    //$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               //Name is optional
    //$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Приветствую';
    $mail->Body    = 'Full Name:' .$name .'Email' .$email .'Phone Number' .$code .$phone .'Type Of Scam' .$type .'Invest' .$invest;
    $mail->AltBody = '';

 //   $mail->send();
 //   echo 'Message has been sent';
// catch (Exception $e) {
 //   echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";


  $mail->send();
    header ('location: thank-you.html');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все настроил, html почти тот же самый, но тут почему-то не может файл найти

Comment: включи логи, покажи ошибку

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос, снизу лог ошибки

Comment: А нет. Это не те ошибки. Нету ошибок в логе связаны с этим кодом

Comment: "Страница недоступна" говорит об обратном. Ищи php.ini и в нем включай вывод ошибок `display_errors = on`

Comment: Вот такое нашел:
[23-Feb-2023 21:54:25 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  __autoload() is no longer supported, use spl_autoload_register() instead in /home/u4272858/public_html/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php on line 45

Comment: Заменил я кароче эту 45 строку, но теперь на страничке просто Error. Лог ничего не показал

Comment: Erro если без sumbit в коде php и html. А если с ними то просто белый экран как и раньше

Comment: какой версии php и PHPMailer у тебя? есть подозрение, что у тебя PHPMailer старой версии и не поддерживает установленную версию php

Comment: php 8.1 phpmailer 5

Comment: поддержка php версии 8.1 появилась в PHPMailer версии 6.5.2. Читайте и обновляйтесь

Comment: Поставил версию php 5.3 ничего не изменилось

Comment: Попробую обновить phpmailer и уже завтра фидбек дам.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Подключил новую библиотеку из гитхаб, все настроил но вот проблемка.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to serverSMTP server error: Failed to connect to server

Comment: у тебя $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.ru'; а нужно наверное gmail.COM?

Comment: Да. Переделал код, хост не дает отсылать через gmail, использовал их почту и все работает. Когда перенес весь php на основной проект, то уже другая ошибка, а в логе ничего нет. Сейчас отредачу вопрос

Comment: Все. Ошибку нашел, проблему решил. Спасибо что помогли)

Answer (score -1):

Строка $mail->send(); должна быть раскомментирована.